# What events are fired for a blocking socket?

Tags: delphi, sockets

Out of curiosity, what events in TServerSocket/TClientSocket are fired if it is a ThreadBlocking type?

Comment: I'm not even remotely an expert, but I wouldn't expect any events to fire for synchronous sockets.

Comment: @David, neither me, but events like for instance [`OnClientRead`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TCustomServerSocket.OnClientRead) must be fired, otherwise the server side wouldn't even be able to read anything from the client.

Comment: @TLama Not the way I read the documentation. As I read it, blocking sockets don't use those events to read and instead use `TWinSocketStream`.

Comment: i am using TWinSocketStream, but for example the OnGetThread event is firing... (including OnListen, OnThreadStart/End), what others ? also where could i find the documentation ?

Comment: @David, from the note; *"If ServerType is stThreadBlocking, make sure that all code in an OnClientRead event handler is thread-safe."*, so it is fired, you just need to use a different reader to get data when this event occurs.

Comment: @user, documentation [TServerSocket Events](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TServerSocket_Events) and [TClientSocket Events](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TClientSocket_Events).

Comment: Event driven synchronous programming? Weird indeed. Is Indy the same?

Comment: @DavidHeffernanת Indy is the same. I don't see anything odd about it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: TServerSocket in blocking mode does fire `OnClientRead` and `OnClientWrite` events by default, just within the context of an internal thread, to preserve the event-driven model in both modes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TClientSocket` in blocking mode fires all of its events except for `OnRead` and `OnWrite`.  Also, the `OnDisconnect` event is not triggered on a remote disconnect, only when the client closes its own end of the socket.  It is the responsibility of code that is reading/writing data to detect these socket states.  Readibility is detected via `TWinSocketStream.WaitForRead()` or the WinSock `select()` function.  Writibility is detected via the WinSock `select()` function only.  Remote disconnect is detected by first detecting readablity and then `TCustomWinSocket.ReceiveBuf()` or `TWinSocketStream.Read()` returning 0.

`TServerSocket` in blocking mode fires all of its events by default.  However, if you derive a class from `TServerClientThread` that overrides the virtual `ClientExecute()` method, and then return an instance of that class from the `OnGetThread` event, then you lose the `OnRead` and `OnWrite` events and have to use similar logic to `TClientSocket` in blocking mode to detect those socket states.

Comment: Last question, inside the ClientExecute, i handle ONLY Read/Write, correct ?

Comment: If you override `ClientExecute()`, then you become responsible for managing the connection. You need to exit from `ClientExecute()` if either `Terminated` is true or the socket is disconnected (the default implementation checks if `ClientSocket.Connected` is false, but there are other ways to detect a disconnect as well). Anything else you do inside of `ClientExecute()` is your own business.

Comment: I thought I did answer your question - if you override `ClientExecute()` then you become responsible for pretty muh EVERYTHING related to that connection, which includes reading and writing.